# Generic quicksort not working for some reason

Tags: c, generic-programming

I'm trying to make a generic quicksort function, and I fail to understand what's wrong with what I'm doing, because it's not working properly.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef bool (*CmpFunction)(void*, void*);

    int cmp(const void *c1, const void *c2)
{
    assert(c1 && c2);
  int a = *(const int*)c1;
  int b = *(const int*)c2;
  if (a > b) return 1;
  if (a < b) return -1;
  return 0;
}

void swap(void *a, void *b, size_t size) {
    char tmp[size];

    memcpy(tmp, a, size);
    memcpy(a, b, size);
    memcpy(b, tmp, size);
}

   void quick_sort(void* a, int n, int size, CmpFunction cmp)
{
   int b = 1, t = n - 1;
   if (n < 2)
      return;
   swap((char*)a, (char*)a+(n/2)*size, size);
   char p = *(char*)a;
   while(b <= t) {
      while(t >= b && cmp((char*)a + t*size, &p) >= 0)
         t--;
      while(b <= t && cmp((char*)a + b*size, &p) < 0)
         b++;
      if (b < t)
         swap((char*)a+size*(b++), (char*)a+size*(t--), size);
   }
   swap((char*)a, (char*)a+t*size, size);
   quick_sort(a, t, size, cmp);
   n=n-t-1;
   quick_sort((char*)a + (t + 1)*size, n, size, cmp);
}
```

While the original quicksort function, without me trying to make it generic is:

```
void quick_sort(int a[], int n)
{
   int p, b = 1, t = n - 1;
   if (n < 2)
      return;
   swap(&a[0], &a[n/2]);
   p = a[0];
   while(b <= t) {
      while(t >= b && a[t] >= p )
         t--;
      while(b <= t && a[b] < p)
         b++; 
      if ( b < t) 
         swap(&a[b++], &a[t--]);
   }
   swap(&a[0], &a[t]);
   quick_sort(a, t);
   n=n-t-1;
   quick_sort(a + t + 1, n);
}

void swap(int *c1, int *c2)
    {
      int c = *c1;
      *c1 = *c2;
      *c2 = c;
    }
```

I'm using this main():

```
    int main(){

    char b[] = {'a','t','b','c','y','s'};
    int c[] = {1,4,6,3,5,7};
    quick_sort(c, 6, sizeof(c[0]), &cmp);

    for (int i=0;i<6;i++)
        printf("%d | ", c[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Now we all agree that the output should be:

```
1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

which is indeed what I get when running the NOT generic function.
When I run my generic(upper) function I get this:

```
5 | 1 | 4 | 7 | 6 | 3 |
```

You all have any ideas where I'm wrong? :)

Comment: Did you try debugger? Or printing intermediate results? (or qsort function)

Comment: @MohitJain extremely hard to debug with all these voids. Eclipse won't show me current values. Do you know another way to debug?

Comment: Google this "how to debug small C code"

Comment: In the generic version you have: `char p = *(char*)a;` did you mean `char* p` ? Otherwise this code doesn't make sense.

Comment: @2501 Why not? I'm sending the address of 'p' to cmp()

Comment: @DanBreak `char p` only contains a single character. By passing its address you're comparing a `char` as if it were an `int`. This is nonsense and also undefined behavior.

Comment: @2501 I'm a bit confused, sorry for my lack of knowledge. How can I pass p then?

Comment: @DanBreak Use a character pointer to store the address of the pivot.

Comment: @2501 I still don't see the difference. You want me to save the address in another pointer, and then send that pointer? How is this different from sending the pointer's address?

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int integerCompare(const void *c1, const void *c2) // use this to compare int
{
    int a = *(const int*) c1;
    int b = *(const int*) c2;
    if (a > b) {
        return 1;
    } else if(a < b) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}


int characterCompare(const void *c1, const void *c2) // use this to compare char
{
    char a = *(const int*) c1;
    char b = *(const int*) c2;
    if (a > b) {
        return 1;
    } else if(a < b) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}



void swap(void *a, void *b, size_t size) {
    // instead of using an array, use a void pointer and malloc 
    void* tmp = malloc(size);
    memcpy(tmp, a, size);
    memcpy(a, b, size);
    memcpy(b, tmp, size);
    free(tmp); // free the allocated space
}

void quick_sort(void* a, int n, int size, int (*cmp)(const void*, const void*))
{
    int b = 1;
    int t = n - 1;
    if (n < 2) {
        return;
    }
    swap(a, a + (n/2) * size, size); // &a[0] == a
    // you do not need that p variable .. its value is not being modified
    while(b <= t) {
      while(t >= b && cmp(a + t*size, a) >= 0)
         t--;
      while(b <= t && cmp(a + b*size, a) < 0)
         b++;
      if (b < t)
         swap(a + size * (b++), a + size * (t--), size);
   }
   swap(a, a + t * size, size);
   quick_sort(a, t, size, cmp);
   n= n - t - 1;
   quick_sort(a + (t + 1)*size, n, size, cmp);
}

int main()
{
    char b[] = {'a','t','b','c','y','s'};
    int c[]  = {1,4,6,3,5,7};

    quick_sort(c, 6, sizeof(c[0]), &integerCompare);
    for (int i=0;i<6;i++) {
        printf("%d | ", c[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    quick_sort(b, 6, sizeof(b[0]), &characterCompare);
    for (int i=0;i<6;i++) {
        printf("%c  | ", b[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @downvoter Is the code not working for you or what is the problem, if I may ask?